# How is 1 greater than 4?

Tags: java, collections, set, treeset

The [`NavigableSet.lower(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#lower%28E%29) Javadoc says it returns the greatest element in this set strictly less than the given element, or `null` if there is no such element. Why is 1 the output here? Shouldn't it be 4?

```
NavigableSet original = new TreeSet();
original.add("1");
original.add("2");
original.add("3");
original.add("4");
original.add("10");
Object lower = original.lower("10");
System.out.println(lower);
```

Answer (score 7):

Because the values are `String`(s) the `Set` is comparing by [lexical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). Please, don't use [`Raw Types`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

```
NavigableSet<Integer> original = new TreeSet<>();
original.add(1);
original.add(2);
original.add(3);
original.add(4);
original.add(10);
Object lower = original.lower(10);
System.out.println(lower);
```

Output is

```
4
```

Answer (score 3):

thats because you are comparing Strings here, and not as assumed integers. So the actual order in the Set is : 1, 10, 2, 3, 4 !

Use the generics : `NavigableSet<Integer> original = new TreeSet<>();` and add the values as integers :
`original.add(1);` and so on.